# How do you import contacts into Twilio SMS?

Tags: twilio

How do you import contacts into Twilio SMS (phone numbers for texting)? This is so simple yet nothing in this app I can find lets you import contacts, please help!

Also how do you know the phone number you have for a contact is a Whatsapp number?

Is there software that identifies the Whatsapp numbers from a list of phone numbers that are mostly landlines but a few are cell or other type numbers that are registered on Whatsapp?

Comment: Hello @william-diving, welcome to the Stackoverflow. There are multiple questions in your request. Please one question at a time and consider creating another question for others. Meanwhile, which technology are you using with the Twilio ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio does not store your contacts, so there is no way to import contacts. When you want to [send an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) you provide the number you want to send the message to, the Twilio number you are sending from and the body of the message. There is no need for a contact.

Within Twilio Notify, which is a way to send bulk notifications, you can [create Bindings](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource). A Binding is a resource that binds an identity to an address and an address type, for example an phone number for an SMS or an APNS device token for push notifications on iOS. Once you have a number of bindings stored, you can [send a notification to them](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource).

> Also how do you know the phone number you have for a contact is a WhatsApp number?

When using the WhatsApp API to send messages, [you must receive explicit opt-in from your users that you can contact them via WhatsApp](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017773294-Rules-and-Best-Practices-for-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio#h_06ee4910-7d2a-4587-af05-ec76af5ab25d). So, you should not try to search through existing contact numbers to find out whether they are also a WhatsApp number, instead, you should get your user's consent to send to their WhatsApp number and record the number then.